# Android Listview ArrayAdapter error

Tags: android, listview, android-arrayadapter

I`m trying to create custum listview. But something is going wrong. the problem is in isRight
variable.  When I print out this message.user.id.equals(current_user.id);
everything works. 
What did I do wrong?

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // Get the data item for this position
    Message message = getItem(position);

    Boolean isRight = message.user.id.equals(current_user.id);

    TextView message_text;
    TextView message_date;

    if (isRight) {
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.owner_message, parent, false);
        }
        message_text = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.owner_message_text);
        message_date = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.owner_message_date);
    } else {
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.gest_message, parent, false);
        }
        message_text = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.gest_message_text);
        message_date = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.gest_message_date);
    }

    message_text.setText(message.text);
    message_date.setText(DateUtil.convertDateToContextFormatText(message.date, this.context));

    return convertView;
}
```

Comment: What is exactly the issue ?

Answer (score 0):

I`m not 100% sure, but couldn`t be a problem with recycling views and that convertView is not null and have loaded wrong layout. Remove condition `convertView == null` and try if it helps.